# Best type of specialist who performs colonoscopies

Tags: gastroenterology, colon, intestine, colonoscopy

I googled for the best type of specialist who performs colonoscopies and it says gastroenterologist [[link 1](https://bottomlineinc.com/health/health-care-professionals/which-type-of-doctor-should-do-your-colonoscopy), [link 2](https://patients.gi.org/gi-health-and-disease/your-doctor-has-ordered-a-colonoscopy-what-questions-should-you-ask/)]. My questions:

1. Why don't they mention *colorectal surgeon*? One would think that a colorectal surgeon is more specialized in the digestive system.
2. Would it matter if the patient has anal stenosis?

Comment: I edited your question in an attempt to make it general and not a request for personal medical advice, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Anal Stenosis, I think, is commonly seen in newborns or infants.
This needs treatment by itself.

A adult person having "Anal Stenosis", if he/she is passing stools normally, then he can, as well go for Colonoscopy.

Colo-Rectal surgeons do surgeries, like complications Crohn's disease or Ulcerative Colitis or Megacolon, resection of Colon cancer etc.

Colonoscopy/Endoscopy is a different speciality where the physicians get training in looking, excising small polyps, taking biopsies etc. They are not trained in surgery. If the lesion is beyond the scope of Gastro-Enterologist, then it has to be dealt with by a surgeon. Colo-rectal surgeries, some of them can be done endoscopically, in an operation theatre, just in case, if anything goes wrong, they should be ready for Laparatomy (opening of the abdomen)

Comment: To give some background info, my Dad got piles surgery in 1965 in India (age 20). Over the decades the anus got narrow. In 2008 (age 63) my Dad got surgery in USA to expand size of anus. Colon-rectal surgeon did bad job and size of anus decreased further, plus inelasticity. Recent examination shows ulcers. He is scared to go for bowel movement as it is Burning, Itching, Paining, Bleeding (due to ulcers). Suppositories barely help, and all the laxatives he takes barely helps. Would colonoscopy help my Dad. Or shall we research Colon-rectal surgeon to manage the condition (no more surgery).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that. 
Hemorrhoidal surgery does not go as deep as anal sphincter. Somebody must have cut his anal sphincter and tried to repair which might have resulted in Anal Stenosis.

Once you have ulcers etc at the anus, you need colonoscopy to rule out any Crohn’s disease or ulcerative colitis.

If there is no other pathology, manual anal dilatation can be attempted under anesthesia in several installments

I do not know if your father forms lot of scar when he gets a scar.
That could be a problem. Some steroids may have to be used during the healing process after the procedure.

Other option is Colostomy and give some rest to the anus.
During that time, Anal stenosis can be dealt with.
Once anal stenosis is satisfactorily corrected, then colostomy can be closed. This is my opinion

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance and views. Colostomy - ouch, that is rather invasive. Steroids, on the other hand, I suppose we can ask about. I understand this is also last effort since they are so strong. We are looking for least invasive as possible. Thanks once again.

Comment: How old is your father? what are other risk factors? what is his quality of life?

Comment: You are sounding that Anal Stenosis is not bothersome. He is managing it well somehow. Stenosis is Fibrosis like a scar. what can you do for that.?

Comment: Manual anal dilatatation in step-wise manner can be attempted but as it is very painful it has to be done under general anesthesia. With my limited knowledge, that is my opinion.Thank you

Comment: Actually it is quite bothersome for my Dad. In addition, he has severe debilitating anal itch, caused by topical compound cream to treat the anal ulcers. Will post visual info in next day or so (words cannot begin to describe the pain he is enduring)

Comment: I posted background info at https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/how-to-simplify-patient-visual-info-for-doctors. Totally understand this site does not provide medical guidance.